# how to insert a hyperlink to cite the author's name/year

Tags: packages, citing

I have been struggling to provide a hyperlink to the author's name and year I have used in my bibliography file (doc.bib). Does anyone have a MWE to provide in this case or let me know what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

This is the code I have used so far:

doc.bib

```
@article{abcd:2006a,
  author      = "Torben G. Andersen and Tim Bollerslev and 
                Peter F. Christoffersen and Francis X. 
                Diebold",
  title       = "Volatility and correlation forecasting",
  chapter     = 15,
  pages       = "777--878",
  editor      = "Graham Elliott and Clive W. J. Granger and 
                Allan Timmermann",
  booktitle   = "Handbook of Economic Forecasting, 
                Volume~1",
  publisher   = "Elsevier",
  address     = "Amsterdam",
  year        = 2006,
}
```

doc.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\doc}{F:/Datasets/KLIPS/data/wave_01_13/tex/1.Introduction/final}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
Bla bla \cite{abcd:2006a}. 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\doc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not tested, but `hyperref` usually is the last package loaded.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for your reply. The same problem appears even when hyperref is the last one loaded. Instead of author/year there is a question mark.

Comment: Did you compile multiple times and called `bibtex` inbetween? Works here.

Comment: @Johannes_B That was the case. After compiling in this order: PDFLaTex BibTex PDFLaTex PDFLaTex PDFview it worked. Thanks again.